# Proving that this preimage of a bounded set is bounded.

Tags: calculus

Define $m(t)=\int^t_0 f(s)ds$, for $t\in \mathbb{R}^+$ with $f\in \mathbb{R}^+_0$, and $m^{<-}(x)=\inf\{u:m(u)\geq x\}$.

Is there a way to prove that for any bounded set $B$, we have $(m^{<-})^{-1}(B)$ is also bounded?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that $\int_0^\infty f(s)ds < \infty $, take $B$ bounded. This means $B \subseteq [0,n]$ for a fixed $n\in\Bbb{N}$. Because of $(m^{<-})^{-1}(B) \subseteq (m^{<-})^{-1}([0,n])$ it suffices to show that the right set is bounded. Indeed,
$$(m^{<-})^{-1}([0,n]) = \{x: \inf\{u : m(u)\geq x\}\leq n\}$$
If we asumme this set is not bounded, for every $R>0$ there exists a $x>R$ such that $\inf\{u : m(u)\geq x\}\leq n$. But then 
$$\int_0^n f(s)ds = \infty$$
because $f \geq 0$. Contradiction.Thus $(m^{<-})^{-1}([0,n])$ is bounded.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I haven't had much time to check the reasoning. I'll do it this weekend, and get back to you. ;)

Comment: the weekend came sooner...